# Why if statement stay after the expression

Tags: python, for-loop

Why the if statement stay after the expression in this code:

```
def checkio(number):
    """
    Convert into the string and iterate.
    """
    res = 1
    for d in str(number):
        res *= int(d) if int(d) else 1
    return res
```

Comment: it's a ternary expression. Pretty useless and underperformant

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: Assuming `number` is already an `int`, then `int(d)` is guaranteed to succeed. If it's not an `int`, I'd rather see `checkio` raise an exception than silently replace a non-numeric "digit" with 1.

Comment: @chepner It's checking if the int is 0. When `d` is not convertable into an integer, this will still raise an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a ternary operator (or [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)), here a very underperformant way of writing:

```
di = int(d)
if di:
   res *= di
```

no need to convert twice to integer, or to multiply by one if `di` is 0. In this case, using a ternary expression isn't a good choice.

Comment: Or just do `res *= int(d) or 1`

Comment: yeah, it's slightly better than the original form, but still multiplies by 1 when not needed.